# CSG Modeling in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, modeling, csg

I am dealing with Constructive Solid Geometry(CSG) modeling with OpenGL.

I want to know how to implement binary operation. I read something about *Gold Feather Algorithm* and I know about [*OpenCSG*](http://www.opencsg.org/) but after reading [its source code](https://github.com/openscad/OpenCSG), I found it too complicated to understand. I just need a simple shortest OpenGL example how to implement it.

There's no restrict in Algorithm as long as it is easy to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nicol Bolas is correct - OpenGL will not help with CSG, it only provides a way to draw 3D things onto a 2D screen.
OpenCSG is essentially "fake" CSG by using using OpenGL's depthbuffers, stencils and shaders to make it *appear* that 3D objects have had a boolean operation performed on them.

CSG is a huge task and I doubt you will ever find an "algorithm easy to understand"
Have a look at this project: http://code.google.com/p/carve/ which performs CSG on the triangles/faces which you would then draw to OpenGL

Comment: Are there any articles about how to use `OpenGL's depthbuffers, stencils and shaders` to implement it?

Comment: OpenCSG will be the best place to find out, but as you found it complicated then I'd recommend the openGL Red Book - I always go back to that when looking to understand openGL better: www.amazon.com/OpenGL-Programming-Guide-Official-Learning/dp/0321552628

Answer (score 7):

OpenGL will not help you. OpenGL is a *rendering* library/API. It draws points, lines and triangles; it's up to *you* to tell it what to draw. OpenGL does not maintain a scene or even has a notion of coherent geometric objects. Hence CSG is not something that goes into OpenGL.

Comment: I do have a CSG tree and corresponding data structure. But how can I render `intersection` if my data structure tell me to do so?

Comment: I think OpenGL can help, since OpenCSG is based on it. What I need is the algorithm easy to understand.

Comment: Down-voted not only because this answer is unhelpful, but also because there are rendering-oriented approaches to drawing the result of CSG operations; such approaches typically rely heavily on GPU (OpenGL or equivalent) code, so I find this answer misleading.