# extrude cube from glutSolidCube

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have a door made as transformed cube with OpenGL and C++ Codeblocks. I want that door to has a square hole, something like a window. I create cube with **glutSolidCube()**.

There is what i want to achieve:

```
         ----------
        |          |
        |  hole    |
        |  ----    |
 Door-> | |    |   |
        | |    |   |
        |  ----    |
        |          |
         ----------
```

Comment: You cannot cut out something of an existing shape. You will have to remove the gluSolidCube and replace it with your own mesh.

Comment: OpenGL primitives consist of planes only, not solid objects (even though its name seems to suggest this, but it's only to differentiate from its counterpart glutWireCube). OpenGL is not designed with solid modelling in mind and you cannot perform boolean operations with its objects. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10860710/2564301 for more information.